# ELSE '60+' not working in CASE statement but ELSE 'Others' working

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, case

Here is a SQL statement I use to find how many people are in given age ranges (in percents).

```
SELECT
CASE 
WHEN FLOOR(DATEDIFF(NOW(), adherent_naissance)/365.4) <= 10 THEN '-10' 
WHEN FLOOR(DATEDIFF(NOW(), adherent_naissance)/365.4) <= 20 THEN '11-20'
    WHEN FLOOR(DATEDIFF(NOW(), adherent_naissance)/365.4) <= 30 THEN '21-30'
    WHEN FLOOR(DATEDIFF(NOW(), adherent_naissance)/365.4) <= 60 THEN '31-60'
ELSE '60+' 
END AS Age, 
(Count(adherent_naissance)* 100 / (Select Count(*) From adherent)) as Pourcentage
FROM adherent
GROUP BY 
CASE 
WHEN Age <= 10 THEN '-10' 
WHEN Age <= 20 THEN '11-20'
    WHEN Age <= 30 THEN '21-30'
    WHEN Age <= 60 THEN '31-60'
ELSE '60+' 
END
```

All is working fine except when someone falls in the "Else" category, then I have a strange behaviour : the person is counted in the previous category.

That is to say I got :

```
Age     Pourcentage
11-20   33.3333
21-30   33.3333
31-60   33.3333
```

Instead of :

```
Age     Pourcentage
11-20   33.3333
21-30   33.3333
31-60   16.6667
60+     16.6667
```

`ELSE '60'` doesn't work either but `ELSE 'Others'` does work...

Any idea ? Thanks !

NOTE (test data) : `SELECT adherent_naissance FROM adherent WHERE 1` returns

```
adherent_naissance
1991-01-09
1990-03-28
1995-09-10
1964-01-10
1992-08-19
1920-02-21
```

If it helps, I'm using MySQL 5.5.24-log.

Comment: Could you give an test data of that, please?

Comment: @AlexanderFedorenko `SELECT adherent_naissance FROM adherent WHERE 1` returns
`1991-01-09  
1990-03-28  
1995-09-10  
1992-08-19  
1920-02-21`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add the same CASE expression into GROUP BY clause

```
SELECT
CASE 
WHEN FLOOR(DATEDIFF(NOW(), adherent_naissance)/365.4) <= 10 THEN '-10' 
WHEN FLOOR(DATEDIFF(NOW(), adherent_naissance)/365.4) <= 20 THEN '11-20'
    WHEN FLOOR(DATEDIFF(NOW(), adherent_naissance)/365.4) <= 30 THEN '21-30'
    WHEN FLOOR(DATEDIFF(NOW(), adherent_naissance)/365.4) <= 60 THEN '31-60'
ELSE '60+' 
END AS Age, 
(Count(adherent_naissance)* 100 / (Select Count(*) From adherent)) as Pourcentage
FROM adherent
GROUP BY 
CASE 
WHEN FLOOR(DATEDIFF(NOW(), adherent_naissance)/365.4) <= 10 THEN '-10' 
WHEN FLOOR(DATEDIFF(NOW(), adherent_naissance)/365.4) <= 20 THEN '11-20'
    WHEN FLOOR(DATEDIFF(NOW(), adherent_naissance)/365.4) <= 30 THEN '21-30'
    WHEN FLOOR(DATEDIFF(NOW(), adherent_naissance)/365.4) <= 60 THEN '31-60'
ELSE '60+' 
END
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5f2e9/4)

Comment: Marvelous ! Any idea why I can't use `Age` as defined in the `SELECT` statement ?

Comment: @Cafeine If you were running MySQL in ANSI mode (or if you turn on `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`) you would have gotten an error message regarding an "invalid" group by (as with all other DBMS)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm very much obliged to you;)